# Integer to custom type conversion in Ada

Tags: indexing, types, integer, type-conversion, ada

I have an array of some kind of objects, indexed by a type `index`:

```
type index is new Integer range 1..50;
type table is new Array(index) of expression;
```

Now, I need to access one of these expressions, depending on a user entry by keyboard. For that I do following:

```
c: Character;
get(c);

s: String := " ";
s(1) := c;
```

Finally I can cast the character to type `Integer`:

```
i: Integer;
i := Integer'Value(s);
```

Now, I have the position of the value the user want to access, but Ada doesn't let you access to `table`, because it is indexed by `index` and not `Integer`, which are different types.

What would be the best solution, to access an expression based on the user's input?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a type conversion? Easy, `Index(i)`. However, you could convert the `Character` directly to `Index`: `Index'Value(s)`

Comment: You might want to `get` a string rather than a character, because using a character with this algorithm will only let you get at the first 9 elements of `table`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
type index is new Integer range 1..50;
type table is new Array(index) of expression;
```

You don't need (and can't have) the `new` keyword in the declaration of `table`.

```
c: Character;
get(c);

s: String := " ";
s(1) := c;
```

The last two lines can be written as:

```
S: String := (1 => C);
```

(assuming that `C` is visible and initialized at the point where `S` is declared).

```
i: Integer;
i := Integer'Value(s);
```

This is not a "cast". Ada doesn't have casts. It's not even a type conversion. But I understand what you mean; if `C = '4'`, then `S = "4"`, and `Integer'Value(S) = 4`. (You should think about what to do if the value of `C` is not a decimal digit; that will cause `Integer'Value(S)` to raise `Constraint_Error`.)

> Now, I have the position of the value the user want to access, but Ada
>   doesn't let you access to `table`, because it is indexed by `index`
>   and not `Integer`, which are different types.

Simple: Don't use different types:

```
I: Index := Index'Value(S);
```